Debian update-alternatives vs Red Hat alternatives
Since CentOS 7 is at its EOL, I am trying to migrate to Ubuntu. Many of our setups involve alternatives to be configured. In Ubuntu, there is no alternatives command but there is an update-alternatives.
alternatives
alternatives version 1.26 - Copyright (C) 2001 Red Hat, Inc.
This may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU Public License.

update-alternatives --version
Debian update-alternatives version 1.19.7.

This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.

Are they the same? Are all the commands interchangeable between these two?
Can I just symlink alternatives to update-alternatives in Ubuntu? Is it just the command name that is different?

Crossposted: https://askubuntu.com/q/1519015/158442

If you are experienced with and/or comfortable with CentOS 7, why not upgrade to Rocky/OEL/Alma 8 or 9? Mostly the same interface and you don't have to learn the details of Ubuntu.

The commands are very similar but they’re not interchangeable — each variant has features the other one doesn’t. In many instances you’ll be able to use update-alternatives instead of alternatives, but it’s best to review each instance rather than symlink alternatives to update-alternatives.
